# PHP exec sendsms (smstools3) permission denied (chown/mktemp)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, shell, apache2

I'm using Debian with apache2, php5 and mysql.
My goal is to send sms through a php call. For sending SMS I'm using smstools3.

Using my php script, I get the error:

> chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/smsd_PW0kUD': Operation not permitted
>
> mktemp: failed to create file via template'/var/spool/sms/outgoing/send_XXXXXX': Permission denied
>
> mv: missing destination file operand after '/tmp/smsd_PW0kUD'

My php code - the sms command is " sendsms 4912312312 'text' ":

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms(number, text) VALUES('".$Number."','".$Text."')");
$User = escapeshellcmd($User);
$Pw = escapeshellcmd($Pw);
$Nummer = escapeshellcmd($Number);
$Text = escapeshellcmd($Text);
$cmd = "sendsms " . $Nummer . " '" . $Text . "'";
exec($cmd);
```

I already tried chown on tmp & /var/spool/sms to www-data, but it didn't work out (root has now back /spool/sms). I tried different solutions, but neither did work for me.

```
root@xxxx:~# ls -l /var/www/html/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2774 Mai 17 12:54 info.php

root@xxxx:~# ls -l /tmp
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 24 Mai 17 13:06 smsd_7Yrox1

root@xxxx:~# ls -l /var/spool/sms
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai 17 13:08 checked
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai 17 12:49 incoming
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai 17 13:07 outgoing
```

If I give www-data ownership of /var/spool/sms/ beside /tmp/ I have only this kind of error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/smsd_Q9k4Wt': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Post that part of the code where you're calling sms-sending function.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I tried avoiding the bash and it works executing the command, but now I have permission problems I think. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Try out to place your temporary files in your DocumenRoot, create a tmp/ dir there.

Comment: I can't. The smstools are defining the /tmp directory as place for the sms. I tried now chown tmp | spool/sms to www-data:smsgroup - I added www-data&smsd (the sms user of the tool) to the group. Well now I still get the one not permitted line of temp, but somehow the log of smstools says, that a sms has been sent - but nothing arrives. Before I tried changing some permissions the command worked well, I think it says it has sent it, but couldn't because it doesn't has the permission to do so. Now also the files inside /tmp/ are getting cleared, even if the error is there.

Comment: Did you change ownership over `/var/spool/sms` recursively? If you didn't, do it then: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/spool/sms`

Comment: Yes, I did:  `chown -R www-data:smsgroup /var/spool/sms/` so the apache user has ownership, but the group with apache user and sms user (smsd) have both rights. Still I get the error, but it moves the files - sadly even if log says sms sent, it doesn't - normally it worked before, and I don't know if it happend now through the permission changes.

Comment: Under what user do you start smsd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112159/discussion-between-idragon-and-sergey-brodin).